Можно ли отправлять один проект на GitHub и GitLab в PyCharm?
Как в PyCharm сделать так, чтобы проект пушился и в GitHub и в GitLab? В GitHub отправляется нормально, а от GitLab не нашел как отправить, хотя плагин установлен, аккаунт через токен подключил.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ci_cd_for_external_repos/github_integration.html, https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror, https://dev.to/brunorobert/github-and-gitlab-sync-44mn
